# Jump to byte address in vim?

Tags: vim, binary, hexdump

I'm investigating a mainly UTF-8 file with lot of long lines.  However, the file is not entirely text file, there is some garbage.  To find my point of interest I'm using `hd` and `grep`.

So at some point I know it'm interested in e.g. 0000301a, so I want to quickly open the file in Vim and jump to that position.

Example (actually a tiny file, here the position is 0000001c):

```
me@here:~$ hd file | grep -C 10 \ 00\ 
00000000  6c 69 6e 65 31 0a 6c 69  6e 65 32 0a 6c 69 6e 65  |line1.line2.line|
00000010  33 0a 6c 69 6e 65 34 0a  6c 69 6e 65 00 35 0a 6c  |3.line4.line.5.l|
00000020  69 6e 65 36 0a 6c 69 6e  65 37 0a 6c 69 6e 65 38  |ine6.line7.line8|
00000030  0a 6c 69 6e 65 39 0a 6c  69 6e 65 31 30 0a        |.line9.line10.|
0000003e
me@here:~$
```

Is there a trick in Vim to jump to a *byte position*?  Or as close as possible?

Comment: Not sure if this will work in your case, but have you tried converting the offset to decimal then using `:goto 1234`?

Comment: You don't have to use hexadecimal numbering by the way, you can format the hd output any way you want. Take a look at the man page.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's the normal mode command `go`.

From [`:h go`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#go):

> **[count]go**         Go to {count} byte in the buffer.

For example, `42go` jumps to byte 42.

In order to jump to a hexadecimal or octal address you would need to construct a command with `:normal! go` or the equivalent `:goto`, and the `str2nr()` or `printf()` function.

```
:exe 'normal! ' . str2nr('0x2a', 16) . 'go'
:exe 'goto' str2nr('0x2a', 16)
```

Comment: Watch out though: Vim's byte positions are 1-based (like the column and line numbers), not zero-based.

Answer (score 6):

While this question has merit of its own, may I suggest that you're doing this whole thing in a rather roundabout fashion, using all of `hd`, `grep`, Vim, and the shell?

Why not use Vim and only Vim for the whole process?

The key is at [`:h 23.4`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_23.html#23.4), "Binary files": Vim can be your hex editor.

After starting Vim with your file, `vim -b myfile`, the workflow becomes:

```
:%!xxd -g1<Enter>
/00 <Enter>
...
...
:%!xxd -r<Enter>
```

Be sure to read [`:h hex-editing`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#hex-editing), too, for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using `:help starting.txt` you can find the help about all vim command line arguments.

Using the above goto command given by several others you should be able to give vim a command from the command line to go to the byte offset such as

`vim "+exe 'goto' str2nr('0x2a', 16)" file`

There is a compile time flag described at `:help +byte_offset` you can check for using the `:ve` command. My Ubuntu version has it compiled in by default.

Comment: `vim --version | grep byte_offset` and look for a `+` or `-` is generally faster that scanning `:version`

Comment: Although `:echo has("byte_offset")` is even faster. Just check to see that the output is a 1.